# Why does a dynamic_cast of a reference fail to compile if the base class has a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

I ran into this problem below and am looking for understanding. In my application I have a base class with a pure virtual that takes a reference to the base class (think: to make a copy). In the derived class I cast the reference to the derived class. This works fine until I add a unique_ptr of the base class to the base class. If I change the cast from a reference to a pointer all is well, but I don't get it. Sample code:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    void hello() const { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
protected:
    virtual void cvt( Base& ) const = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> any_member_unique_ptr;                    // "A"
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { std::cout << "new Derived" << std::endl; }
    void cvt( Base& in ) const override {
        const auto cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );  // "B"
        const auto cast_okay = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>( &in );
        hello();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived D, P;
    D.cvt( P );
}
```

If the line commented as "A" ***or*** the line commented as "B" is commented out, the program compiles and runs fine (note that the member at "A" is never used). However, with both lines present g++ 11.3.0 reports:

```
tt.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Derived::cvt(Base&) const’:
tt.cpp:17:69: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived::Derived(const Derived&)’
   17 |      const auto cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );  // "B"
      |                                                              ^

tt.cpp:13:7: note: ‘Derived::Derived(const Derived&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   13 | class Derived : public Base {
      |       ^~~~~~~
tt.cpp:13:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Base::Base(const Base&)’
tt.cpp:4:7: note: ‘Base::Base(const Base&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    4 | class Base {
      |       ^~~~
tt.cpp:4:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Base; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:76,
                 from tt.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:468:7: note: declared here
  468 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: tt] Error 1
```

If I guru meditate on it long enough I think I can make out what it's saying (the copy-by-reference constructor for the unique_ptr is deleted) but I still don't get why casting a reference to the object would be different from casting a pointer to it.

Is there a general rule or idiom for this? I can "make it work" by just using the pointer, but I prefer references when possible.

Comment: Dynamic cast is fine, you can't copy `Base`.

Comment: Because `const auto cast_fail = ...` defines `cast_fail` as an *object*, not a reference. Use `const auto& cast_fail` to define a reference.

Comment: If you want a reference, you need to add that to `auto` as well. `const auto cast_fail` -> `const auto& cast_fail`

Comment: Okay, I'm dumb. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const auto cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );  // "B"
```

This line casts to `Derived&` and then makes a copy. You can't copy `unique_ptr` (that's what `unique` means) so you also can't copy anything that has a `unique_ptr` in it.

But if you change it to `const auto& cast_fail`, then `cast_fail` will be a reference to a `Derived`, instead of a separate `Derived` object, and it will work.

`cast_okay` works because `cast_okay` is a pointer and nothing is copied.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the reference fails is because it is not included with the `auto` type

```
const auto cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );
const auto cast_okay = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>( &in );
```

written explicitly this is

```
const Derived cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );
const Derived* cast_okay = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>( &in );
```

note in the reference case this is casting to `const Derived&` but then assigning to a value, which will attempt a copy, and therefore fail since the class is non-copyable due to having a `std::unique_ptr` member which is non-copyable.

Either of these would work

```
const auto& cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );
const Derived& cast_fail = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>( in );
```

Comment: `decltype(auto) cast_fail = ...` also works.